# How to manage sound in java spring boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I have a list of all the accounts that have access to the system displayed on the admin screen.
[image]

I want the administrator to be able to enable and disable the system sounds of the client computers. I am using java spring, js.
How can I do that on java spring?

Comment: What kind of sound?

Comment: I am using a laptop so I want to turn off the computer's sound.

Comment: You want to turn off/on the native sound of the OS (e.g. windows) and your client is running within the browser?

Comment: Yes!!! I using Chrome